# Get the first and last item from a range

Tags: vba, excel

I defined a range in VBA using the following code

```
    Range("D3").Select
    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
```

For I would like to do now is perform a function for all elements in the range except the first and last item.

So the code looks like this:

```
    Range("D3").Select
    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

 For Each cell In x

       'if not first or last item

       'Do something        
    Next cell
```

However I can seem to get the first and last item. If I do something like
x[1] of x(1) I get an error. Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

Comment: I recommend reading through [how to avoid select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: @Kyle , valid point +1. I update my answer to get rid of `Select`

Comment: @Kyle I don't use select anymore, but, when I was starting to VBA that helped me to understand what was happening; depending the case, I fix it using the same programmer logic, s/he will eventually notice as a learning curve, pointing him/her in the right direction is a nice way to introduce it :)

Comment: We all start out using it, because it is closer to how we use Excel. I wish I would have learned earlier how to avoid it. It could have saved many headaches and many hours of debugging code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have a control in counter logic, why to use a for each instead a for/to logic?

```
  Range("D3").Select
    Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
TotalRows= Selection.Rows.Count
 For Counter=1 to TotalRows
 If CounterRow <> 1 and CounterRow <> TotalRows Then
       'if not first or last item

       'Do something        
 End If
    Next Counter
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Set x = ... ''<--- your initial range setting, whatever it may be 
For Each cell In x.offset(1).Resize(x.Rows.Count - 2)
       '... your code
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you are performing a change to the cell values, is to load the range values into an array.

Then make the change and write the results back.

```
Sub ChangeValues()

Dim x() As Variant
Dim myItem As Long

Range("D3").Select

x = Range(Range("D3"), Selection.End(xlDown))

    For myItem = LBound(x, 1) + 1 To UBound(x, 1) - 1
       'if not first or last item
       'Do something
       ActiveCell.Offset(myItem - 1, 0) = x(myItem, 1) * 10
    Next myItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way

From your code

```
Range("D3").Select
Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
```

and

```
For i=2 to x.count-1
' here your code do something with x(i)
next i
```

this will leave out the first and last cell of the range selected.